# Opening hours that span 2 days

Tags: schema.org, microdata

How do you mark-up opening hours where the store closes (technically) on the next day, e.g., Monday-Friday the store opens from 9am and closes at 2am the following morning.

Is the following acceptable?

```html
<div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
    Mon-Friday
    <time itemprop="opens" datetime="9:00">9am</time> -
    <time itemprop="closes" datetime="2:00">2am</time>
  </div>
```